# Issue with Bing Map --p_elSource.attachEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, bing-maps, virtual-earth

I am facing major problem with Bing Maps. I am using :
http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3

First I am getting error in firebug as :

```
 this.CreditsFor=function(a,i,j,h)
 {
  var e=[];
  if(a!="undefined"&&a!=null&&typeof m_tableKeys[a]!="undefined"&&
   ........
   MVC_Init_FlatlandView_Drawing();
   MVC_Init_View3D_Drawing()};
   if(typeof closeDependency!="undefined")
       closeDependency("mapcontrol.js")
```

After that I put the .LoadMap() call inside try-catch block. it was throwing exception:

> p_elSource.attachEvent is not a
>   function

I already tried out following solutions whihc were recommended in msdn forums:

- Setting defualt value for VEMapOptions.BirdseyeOrientation before calling LoadMap()
- Ensured that DOCTYPE is there

**This happens only when firebug is enabled.**

Comment: Does anybody else has ever faced similar issue.. or I am the only one out here facing this issue??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zeno,

Are you using FF4? I had the problem in FF4, and it was caused by a race condition where my script was calling VE functions that hadn't been defined yet. I got a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/63774ae4-fc41-471f-b42b-f031ca0f7517).

In particular, note the answer from Josh Unger where he describes using setInterval to wait for an auxiliary library to load and do it's thing.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (eval("typeof VEMap") != "undefined" &&
        document.getElementById("map").attachEvent != undefined)   
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        LoadMap();
    }
}, 10);
```

You'll have to update the sample code to fit your circumstances. The important part is to avoid calling anything in VE until you are sure that the VE script has loaded *and* the auxiliary library has loaded.

People using FF4 reported the problem to me recently. I suspect that something about FF4 compared to FF3 (perhaps faster script execution, or a difference in when scripts execute) has triggered the error. In any case, when I updated my code to delay calling VE until the libs were loaded, the error went away and the maps worked properly.

Note that I am not doing lazy loading, and Firebug is not the issue. Those were evidently factors when the thread was active in 2008/2009.

Comment: This worked for me when I increased the interval; I used 1000 instead of 10.

Comment: What's the need for the `if(eval("typeof VEMap") != "undefined")` ?  Wouldn't `if(window.VEMap)` work too?